# OpenCv Blob tracking of point relative to plane

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, projection, openframeworks

Am doing an installation that tracks blobs using openCv, and projecting graphics over the blobs. Problem is my camera is off and away from the projector.

I'm thinking to get the point's position in relation to the projection's plane, I would need to calibrate by marking out the plane's corners as seen in the camera view.

My problem is how do i use that 4 points info, and then convert the tracked blob from the camera view to the projection plane, so the projected graphic lines up with the tracked blob? Not sure what i should be searching for.

Answer (score 1):

After you detect the 4 corners points, you can calculate the transformation to the projector plane by using [PerspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#Mat%20getPerspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst)).

Once you have this transformation, you could use [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective), to go from one coordinate system to another.

Comment: I'm not actually needing to transform any images. I just need to calculate points. And get the new point. I actually figured it out by reverse engineering a code that did the transformation. But i'm not sure if there's a better way to do it. [link](http://wonderfl.net/c/GFLY)

Comment: You don't have to use the transformation to warp all image, you can just transform your blob coordinate. Once you have the transformation matrix it is pretty straight-forward, see the formula at [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective)

Comment: Oh that sounds about right. Looking at the method, how can i get the transformation matrix?

Comment: If you project the points using your projector, you have their coordinates in the projector system. If you detect them you have their coordinates in your camera system. That is exactly what you need to define a prespective transformation. Use [getPerspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i'm not getting this still.
So I'll need to use getPerspectiveTransform with my 4 points of the plane, and my output.  It'll return a transformation matrix which i use to apply to the point i want to find in the perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm unable to help with a minimal code example at the moment, but I recommend having a look at [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) and it's examples. There is a camera based undistort example, but the wrapper also provides utilities for warping/unwarping perspective via [warpPerspective](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv/blob/master/libs/ofxCv/include/ofxCv/Wrappers.h#L303) and [unwarpPerspective](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv/blob/master/libs/ofxCv/include/ofxCv/Wrappers.h#L303).

Bare in mind ofxCv has handy function to convert to/from `ofImage` to `cv::Mat` like `toCv()` and `toOf()`

ofxCv may make it easier to use the OpenCV functions Elad Joseph recommends (which sound like exactly what you need)